# java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: C and WinError 10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I was trying to Connect and Fetch data from BigQuery Dataset to Local Pycharm Using Pyspark.

I ran this below Script in Pycharm:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .config('spark.jars', "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/spark-bigquery-latest.jar")\
    .getOrCreate()

conn = spark.read.format("bigquery")\
    .option("credentialsFile", "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/google-bq-api.json")\
    .option("parentProject", "Google-Project-ID")\
    .option("project", "Dataset-Name")\
    .option("table", "dataset.schema.tablename")\
    .load()
conn.show()
```

For this I got the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: C
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPath(DependencyUtils.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2(DependencyUtils.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2$adapted(DependencyUtils.scala:145)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:38)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPaths(DependencyUtils.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$4(SparkSubmit.scala:363)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\naveen.chandar\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\BigQueryConnector.py", line 4, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.config('spark.jars', 'C:/Users/naveen.chandar/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/spark-bigquery-latest.jar').getOrCreate()
  File "C:\Users\naveen.chandar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 186, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "C:\Users\naveen.chandar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 376, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "C:\Users\naveen.chandar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 133, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "C:\Users\naveen.chandar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 325, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "C:\Users\naveen.chandar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 105, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

So, I researched and tried it from different Diecrtory like "D-drive" and also tried to fix a static port with  `set PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master spark://<IP_Address>:<Port>"`, but still I got the same error in Pycharm.

Then I thought of trying the same script in local Command Prompt under Pyspark and I got this error:

```
failed to find class org/conscrypt/CryptoUpcalls
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1152, in send_command
    answer = smart_decode(self.stream.readline()[:-1])
  File "C:\Users\naveen.chandar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 985, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "D:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1164, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 381, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "D:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "D:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "D:\spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 336, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o42.showString
```

My Python Version is 3.7.9 and Spark Version is 2.4.7

So either way I ran out of idea's and I appreciate some help on any one of the situation I facing...

Thanks In Advance!!

Answer (score 8):

Start your file system references with `file:///c:/...`

Answer (score 0):

I used

```py
my_conf.set("spark.jars","D:\Data\spark-avro_2.11-2.4.4.jar")
```

in place of

```py
my_conf.set("spark.jars","D:/Data/spark-avro_2.11-2.4.4.jar")
```

and it worked perfectly in Pycharm.

Answer (score -2):

You need to replace <kbd>/</kbd> with <kbd>\</kbd>  for the path to work